# How do I replace a folder with its only subfolder of the same name in CLI?

Tags: shell, command-line, files, move

Suppose that I have *only* the following in `~/foo`:

```
.
..
foo
```

With file managers if I cut the subfolder `foo` and paste it into `~` it automatically replaces the contents of `~/foo` with that of `~/foo/foo`.

But is there a native command-line tool to do so, although I can achieve the goal with a function, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know any way to do it in one step,
but the easiest way around the problem is to remove the problem. 
The fact that the two directories have the same name is a problem;
so, rename one of them:

```
mv foo foo2  &&  mv foo2/foo foo  &&  rmdir foo2
```

Comment: Or with GNU `mv`: `mv -iT foo/foo foo2 && mv -T foo2 foo`. One question would be: _which `foo` would we like to preserve the metadata of?_